# Observing garbage file names after restoring back an encrypted partition (using ecryptfs)

Tags: mount, security, encryption, ecryptfs

I have a special requirement, where I need to rollback the encrypted drive (using ecryptfs) to un-encrypted with its contents untouched. For this task, I am following below steps.

1. Take backup of my encrypted drive contents (say /home mounted to /dev/sda3) to temporary .tgz file stored on a temporary unencrypted drive in my system.
2. Unmount my encrypted folder /home
3. Delete /home and recreate new /home
4. Format my /dev/sda3 with ext3
5. Mount /dev/sda2 to /home
6. Unzip all .tgz contents  to /home

After step-6, I see garbage filenames in my /home folder.
When I checked .tgz file, it contains garbage files in it.
Any reason why these garbage files are gathered in step-1 above. Anyway to avoid this. Please suggest.

If you need additional information please let me know.

Below are sample garbage file names displayed

```
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5D6ewucAr45Lpz.Up5pFON---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5J0oMSIHm6ODyTJAEnMuyPU--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5Ls7skHy0SI306pYhYDdVPE--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5N4O7SgxwwIAheJRFBWjR.---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5RD18uy.MohdmQEtKhCzKbk--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5aPjD6ZKeV9A4zCj9lKR9OU--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5bk9rL114fhD.VUoP36.2Ek--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWYHu94wM71d5EQDu3OhIS0WQ49MjHMLwGT5brAUbYyvXXPQY.HJb4Zv1k--
```

Note : I am using ecryptfs_fnek_sig while mounting ecryptfs folder to encrypt my filenames

Comment: FYI, those are not "garbage file names", they're clearly eCryptfs filenames - the `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.` at the start is a little bit of a hint. Garbage names would be something like completely random non-ASCII characters and such.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue by clearing all contents of my /home directory after taking backup of it.

```
rm -rf /home/*
rm -rf /home.* 2>/dev/null
```

I did this as a part of step 2 above. From debug information, I came to know that step 2 was failing with error rm failed because of "directory not empty". Once after deleting its contents with above commands, I was able to delete it and recreate a new one. From there on, I dont see above error.